# Convert String to Timestamp in Spark/Hive

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I need to convert string to Timestamp.

The problem is that the input is coming from a **csv** file and contains date-time values such as:

`Mar  3 2022  8:30AM`

`Apr 27 2022  7:37AM`

If I use the following conversion:

> to_timestamp(to_timestamp(trim(DateColumn), 'MMM dd yyyy  h:mma'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

It converts the date `Apr 27 2022  7:37AM` correctly, but throws error while converting `Mar  3 2022  8:30AM` because of the extra space between the Month and Date values and that the date 3 is not 03.

Is there a way to convert these 2 strings formats into Datetime?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you first uniformly replace multiple spaces with a `single space`, and then convert to timestamp.

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("ts", to_timestamp(regexp_replace(trim(col("ts")), "\\s+", " "), "MMM d y h:mma"))
```